# Trying to link a form to a custom data table I set up in pgadmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, pgadmin

So I have a custom data table set up and I would like to set that table as a destination for info that goes through my form. How would I go about doing that?

I currently have django and the database linked, but currently I have it set to use the default user_auth table, that django automatically sets up.

Here is my views.py file for more context:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    newuser= User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username)
    newuser.save()
    print(request.POST)
    return redirect('/home')
else: 
    return render(request,'userinfo.html')
```

How would I go about changing the database destination for the form?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I am looking to link a form to specific database table

Comment: Why is tagged pgadmin ?